# Windows Phone 8 User Control with content

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I want to create a gauge like user control that will display in the background a set of rectangles with proportional width based on a certain DataContext object values. Fot the simplicity of problem I hardcoded rectangles drawing in the sample below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.UI.BlockGauge"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/SampleViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    d:DesignWidth="468" 
    d:DesignHeight="120"
    Name="GaugeControl">    

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Margin="0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="RootPanel">
            <Canvas x:Name="BackgroundCanvas"  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=RootPanel}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
                <ContentPresenter Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
                <Rectangle Width="240" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=BackgroundCanvas}" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Canvas.ZIndex="-20" />
                <Rectangle Width="80" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=BackgroundCanvas}" Fill="Green" Canvas.ZIndex="-20" Canvas.Left="240"/>
                <Rectangle Width="40" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=BackgroundCanvas}" Fill="Orange" Canvas.ZIndex="-20" Canvas.Left="320"/>
            </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The main reason I decide to go with userControl is to calculate rectangles basing on a view-model object bound to it.

I want this control to work on backgound only and allow contents being set by a parent. Whenever I set a content - all user control content is overriden by it and I can see a new contents instead of hardcoded rectagles. I want custom content over a dynamic backgroud.

I've tried templating inside the control but it says that Template propterty is not supported for a user control.

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>

    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

How can present a injected content over dynamically drawn background?

Comment: Why not just layer the background beneath the rectangles?

Comment: @WiredPrairie can you explain more? How to manipulate rectangles by code?

Comment: In your user control, just write code to manipulate them? You can have an image Z-ordered below the rectangles in the canvas. You need to write a `control` if you want to add full/easy support for templating, etc.

Comment: oh, I thought you mean some other way.... I have a code to manipulate rectangles in my user control but templating doesn't work

Comment: You'd need to create your own property to store a template and render it using a content control possibly.